# Google Visualization Chart throw alert on Select Event Data

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, google-api, google-visualization

I am attempting to use Googles Visualization column charts to simply throw an alert when a specific column is selected.  Ie.  I want to do something (throw an alert) when Company1's column data is selected:

```
      google.load("visualization", "1", {packages:["corechart"]});
      google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart);
      function drawChart() {
        var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
        data.addColumn('string', 'Date');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Company1');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Company2');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Company3');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Company4');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Company5');
        data.addColumn('number', 'Company6');
        data.addRows([
          ['Feb 1, 2012 - Mar 13, 2012', 10, 10, 5, 15, 10, 55]

        ]);

        var options = {
          title: 'Total Reviews',
          hAxis: {title: '',  titleTextStyle: {color: 'blue'}}
        };

        var chart = new google.visualization.ColumnChart(document.getElementById('total'));
        chart.draw(data, options);

google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
 //SOMETHING GOES HERE WHEN ie. Company1 is selected, probably an IF but I cant seem to let it know when Company1 is selected.
 alert('Company1 was selected!');       

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must call `getSelection` function to retrieve the current selection. Selection is an array of objects. Each object have row and column attributes (if any). Use the column one to retrieve the label name:

```
google.visualization.events.addListener(chart, 'select', function() {
  var selection = chart.getSelection()[0];
  var label = data.getColumnLabel(selection.column);

  if (label === "Company1"){
    alert("!");
  }
});
```

[Documentation](http://code.google.com/intl/es/apis/chart/interactive/docs/reference.html#visgetselection) (follow the link to read more):

> **selection_array:**   An array of selected objects, each one describing a
>   data element in the underlying table used to create the visualization
>   (a DataView or a DataTable). Each object has properties row and/or
>   column, with the index of the row and/or column of the selected item
>   in the underlying DataTable. If the row property is null, then the
>   selection is a column; if the column property is null, then the
>   selection is a row; if both are non-null, then it is a specific data
>   item. You can call the DataTable.getValue() method to get the value of
>   the selected item. The retrieved array can be passed into
>   setSelection()